# Eclipse Does not show Tomcat server logs in terminal console

Tags: eclipse, logging, tomcat8

I've been extensively looking for a very very simple way to display the tomcat ERRORS/WARNINGS logs in my eclipse terminal console, I cannot proceed with my development, because I can't see what error or warnings tomcat might be telling me, here is a sample server log output where I suspect a "no mapping found for http request with uri in dispatcherservlet", but does not being shown in the output

```
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.30 using APR version 1.4.8.
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:43 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:OnlineStudentRegistration' did not find a matching property.
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:43 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:Spring.MVC' did not find a matching property.
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014)
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1799 ms
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.9
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:45 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [107] milliseconds.
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:49 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:49 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Sep 04 14:19:49 PDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:49 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/addStudent],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.osr.controllers.StudentLoginController.studentLogin(com.osr.domain.Student,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.osr.controllers.StudentLoginController.student()
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 2417 ms
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Sep 04, 2014 2:19:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 14373 ms
```

is there any configuration with tomcat? or eclipse I am missing here?

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead

### right click on your project, and click run as...

you will find something occurs on your console. I think it may be a bug!

Comment: that's exactly how I run my project and I don't know if there is any configuration I need to do.

Comment: Wow this answer is both sarcastic, unhelpful, and wrong.